# Enable CORS for Web API 1, .net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, cors

I need to enable CORS for my Web API and I can't upgrade to Framework 4.5 at the moment. (I know about System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute.)

I've tried to add the following to my Web.config to see if it worked, but it didn't:

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

I've also tried to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to "*" manually by use of System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute (based on this post: [Add custom header to all responses in Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349447/add-custom-header-to-all-responses-in-web-api)) - but that didn't work out either as the request is rejected before it gets to the action filtering.

So I'm kinda stuck now.. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Turns out

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
```

was the answer all along, I must've done something wrong previously when I tested it. But this solution means that all actions are CORS enabled (which will do for now).

Comment: possible duplicate of [The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'. Error Code 405](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26487126/the-requested-resource-does-not-support-http-method-get-error-code-405)

Comment: @ArindamNayak The accepted answer in that thread seems to require .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: do one thing, follow, the steps mentioned in answer there, and you may have to search for .net 4 nuget package to make it work. Note: I have answered there, so i not answering it here, i mean not making a copy of that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143378/webapi-cors-for-runtime-4-0 - this says CORS is not there in WEB API 1.- Added my answer too!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try to add also:

```
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
```

Comment: where to add this, I tried adding in web config, but not working

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam add it to web.config https://gist.github.com/walkermatt/637df93121a409faab6a

Comment: I am accessing method from jquery, and it is web api -1

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam it may be better to create a new question for that, like discuss it here.

Comment: I have created a new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36423740/enable-cross-domain-web-api-1

Answer (score 11):

POST, PUT, DELETE, etc use pre-flighted CORS. The browser sends an OPTIONS request. This is because browser first, checks if serverside can handle CORS or not using `OPTIONS` request, if succeeds, then sends actual request `PUT` or `POST` or `Delete`. Since you do not have an action method that handles OPTIONS, you are getting a 405. In its most simplest form, you must implement an action method like this in your controller.

More explanation - http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-preflight-requests

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

```
public HttpResponseMessage Options()
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    return response;
}
```

Note: This this action just responds to `OPTION` request, so along with this you need to add necessary config to `web.config`, such as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin = *` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods = POST,PUT,DELETE`.

`Web API 2` has CORS support, but with Web API 1, you have to follow this path.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the lot of issue with webAPI 1 Cross domain access finally able to fix it have a look at my blog http://keerthirb.blogspot.in/2017/08/making-cross-enable-for-webapi1.html

Cross code is

```
public class CorsHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    const string Origin = "Origin";
    const string AccessControlRequestMethod = "Access-Control-Request-Method";
    const string AccessControlRequestHeaders = "Access-Control-Request-Headers";
    const string AccessControlAllowOrigin = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
    const string AccessControlAllowMethods = "Access-Control-Allow-Methods";
    const string AccessControlAllowHeaders = "Access-Control-Allow-Headers";

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        bool isCorsRequest = request.Headers.Contains(Origin);
        bool isPreflightRequest = request.Method == HttpMethod.Options;
        if (isCorsRequest)
        {
            if (isPreflightRequest)
            {
                return Task.Factory.StartNew<HttpResponseMessage>(() =>
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                    response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowOrigin, request.Headers.GetValues(Origin).First());

                    string accessControlRequestMethod = request.Headers.GetValues(AccessControlRequestMethod).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (accessControlRequestMethod != null)
                    {
                        response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowMethods, accessControlRequestMethod);
                    }

                    string requestedHeaders = string.Join(", ", request.Headers.GetValues(AccessControlRequestHeaders));
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestedHeaders))
                    {
                        response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowHeaders, requestedHeaders);
                    }

                    return response;
                }, cancellationToken);
            }
            else
            {
                return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(t =>
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage resp = t.Result;
                    resp.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowOrigin, request.Headers.GetValues(Origin).First());
                    return resp;
                });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16926887)

Comment: I Agree So i have included cross enable code. For more info user can go to the link.